# Statistic - different question (person's breathing )

Tags: statistics

Research psychologists are interested in finding out whether a person's breathing patterns are affected by a particular experimental treatment. To determine the general respiratory patterns of the $n=30$ people in the study, the researchers collected some baseline measurements - the total ventilation in liters of air per minute adjusted for body size - for each person before the treatment. The data are shown here:

$$\begin{matrix}
5.23 & 7.79 & 5.83 & 5.37 & 4.35 & 5.54 & 6.04 & 5.48 & 6.58 & 4.82 \\
5.92 & 5.38 & 6.34 & 5.12 & 5.14 & 4.72 & 5.17 & 4.99 & 4.51 & 5.70 \\
4.67 & 5.77 & 5.84 & 6.19 & 5.58 & 5.72 & 5.16 & 5.32 & 4.96 & 5.63 
\end{matrix}$$

I want to find the sample mean, median and standard deviation, then I want to construct a stem-and-leaf plot. How could I describe the shape of the distribution? How large or small does a ventilation measurement have to be before it is considered unusual?

thanks for your help :)

I use Mathematica and I obtained : 
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
\mbox{Stem} & \mbox{Leaves} \\ \hline
4 & 45778\\
5 & 00112223445566778889\\
6 & 0236\\
7 & 8 
\end{array}$$

but my teacher said is not ok!

can you help me please:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Sample mean, just add up all the observations and divide the result by the total number of observations.

For Sample median, sort the data and then find the average of $\dfrac{n}{2}$th term and $\left(\dfrac{n}2{+1}\right)$th term (Since the number of observations is even).

For Sample standard deviation, apply the formula,

$$S=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2}{n-1}}$$

Where $S$ is the Sample standard deviation, $X_i$ is the $i$th observation, $\bar{X}$ is sample mean and $n$ is the number of observations.

For the shape of the distribution, you can find the measure of skewness and kurtosis.

The last part is $\text{Sample Mean}\pm\text{Sample Standard Deviation}$.

Comment: For last part is the interval? $$\left[\text{Sample Mean}-\text{Sample Standard Deviation}, \text{Sample Mean}+\text{Sample Standard Deviation}\right].$$ Thanks :)

Comment: Anything greater than $\text{Sample Mean}+\text{Sample Standard Deviation}$ and anything less than $\text{Sample Mean}-\text{Sample Standard Deviation}$ is unusual.

Comment: Can you explain me please, why is **unusual** ? thanks :)

Comment: In simple terms, standard deviation is a measure of how far away from the mean the observations are. For example, the set of observations $\{99,100,101\}$ has lower standard deviation than than the set of observations $\{47,100,153\}$ because the distance of observation from the mean is higher in the latter case. So the standard deviation value gives you the expected distance of an observation from the mean. If an observation is within the standard deviation from the mean, it is not unusual because it is within the expectation bounds.

Answer (score 1):

The mean/average is simply: $\dfrac{\Sigma x}{n}$

To get the median, you need to sort the data from smallest to largest and find the $\dfrac{n+1}{2}th$ term. Since you will get $15.5th$ term, find the mean/average of the $15th$ and $16th$ term.

The standard deviation is given by: $\sqrt{\dfrac{\Sigma x^2}{n} - \left(\dfrac{\Sigma x}{n}\right)^2}$.

As for the stem & leaf diagram, I would make the units as the stem, and the decimals as the leaves.

For instance, the first row will be like this:

```
4 | 45 82
5 | 23 37 48 54 83
6 | 04 58
7 | 79
```

How to fill it:

1. The first number is 5.23, so on the branch with "5", put "23" next to it.
2. Next comes 7.79, put "79" next to "7".
3. Third comes 5.83. Now, you will need to put this in the branch "5", and there, you already have "23". Put it after "23" since $83>23$.
4. Next is 5.37. This goes in the branch "5" as well, and since $23<37<83$, you will put "37" between "23" and "83".

On a computer it's easy to fill in it, but on paper, you will have to sort the sample from smallest to largest, so that you don't miss smaller amounts. In the above case on paper, you would have to cut/erase 83 to make room for 37.

Comment: can you help me with stem and leaf diagram - a short explication, how I should to calculate. thanks

Comment: @luli, I added an explication. Let me know if this helps :)